# Solr exact substring match not working

Tags: solr, solr4

I want to perform exact substring match in [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/), i.e.

```
 am going
```

should match(**including stopwords, in same order**) the document containing

```
  I am going to school
```

The substring is free text entered by end user.
I have set-up my schema.xml as follows:

```
 <fieldType name="c_text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

It's not working. What am I missing out. Please suggest!
I am a newbie to Solr.

Thanks!!

Comment: Substring matching would mean that you want to hit `going` when searching for `oin`. I do not think this is your problem, right? You want to hit by a phrase (words in same order).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should surround the words of your query which form the phrase with "". Like this

> "am going"

Please look here [solr query syntax](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html)

Comment: Yeah that is the answer and I have also figured out ;)

Comment: Google works in a similar way. We need to enclose the substring or phrase in quotes to get the exact match